# C# Regex, formatting a time

Tags: c#, regex, time, format

I'm making a timecard program, where the user enters the start time, end time, and project name. They can click "Add" and it adds the entered details to a listbox.

I don't allow the data to be added unless the start time and end time are formatted like this: `08:14am` It gets annoying, though, having to enter it exactly like that each time, so I decided to, via regexes, have it automatically format. So if you enter `8:14`, it will change it to `08:14am`. How can I accomplish this via `Regex.Replace()`?

If you have any other methods, don't hesitate to list them.

***Edit 1:*** I also have other replacements in mind; for example `814` goes to `08:14am`, and `8` goes to `08:00am`

***Edit 2:*** So Now I'm using this code:

```
string[] formats = { "h:mm", "h", "hh", "hmm", "hhmm", "h:mmtt", "htt", "hhtt" };
DateTime dt = DateTime.ParseExact(t.Text, formats, new CultureInfo("en-US"), DateTimeStyles.None);
t.Text = dt.ToString("hh:mmtt").ToLower();
```

And it replaces some things, like `h:mm` but not others like `h`.

Comment: Would you want 14:30 to be replaced with 02.30pm?

Comment: That would be nice, but not necessary.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you looked at `DateTime.Parse`? It accepts `"08:14am"`, `"8:14"`[1] and other variants, and returns a `DateTime` set to 8:14 am on today's date.

[1] In the UK culture at least -- consider providing a `CultureInfo` parameter depending on whether you want to pay attention to the user's local format preferences, or adopt a fixed format.

> **EDIT** I also have other replacements in mind; for example 814 goes to 08:14am, and 8 goes to 08:00am

Take a look at [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/332de853.aspx): you can provide an array of valid time formats (such as "hh:mm", "hmm", <strike>"h"</strike> etc.)

Comment: Odd - MSDN has a slightly cryptic note about using "H" on its own: _If you do not use date or time separators in a custom format pattern, use the invariant culture for the provider parameter and the widest form of each custom format specifier. For example, if you want to specify hours in the pattern, specify the wider form, "HH", instead of the narrower form, "H"._

Answer (score 1):

Coming at it from a completely different direction, **how about using a mask on the input**?

For example, there are a number of [JavaScript and jQuery tools](http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/javascript-input-masks/) available to do this.

Using this approach retains some user control over the input, and lets the user see their input.

Answer (score 1):

have you considered using a DateTimePicker? Making the user write the time looks like more of a hassle.

See e.g. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datetimepicker.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think regex are overkill for this. Why not simply append the  "am" at the end, in case nto already added is a 2 line code in case you are working with strings in the method.

Comment: But note the 0 at the start of the finished product. I also have other replacements in mind; for example `814` goes to `08:14am`, and `8` goes to `08:00am`

Comment: @TheAdamGaskins: Ah, that requirement changes the problem. Please update the question! For this case, I'd say you might was well build your own very simple parser. I'm not sure regexes would help very much here.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using regular expressions if possible (as others have said, it seems like overkill) and try using datetime formats. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

The "HH" format tag will format the hour as a 24-hour time from 00 to 23. Traditionally, 12 hour times are not zero-padded to the left, but 24 hour times are (at least as often as I see them), probably to avoid confusion between 1800 and 0800 . Alternatively, if you don't want 24 hour times, you could probably just left-pad the hour part of the string with a zero to up to 2 digits.

---

EDIT:

Based on your new requirements, I'd say write a simple parser to let users input "814" meaning "08:14 AM" and make use of the time-formatting functionality for display.